# Building a docker image on wsl

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I got a new machine and am now using wsl for the first time instead of just ubuntu. I am trying to rebuild one of my projects, but I am unable to build the docker image.

When running `docker-compose build` I get the error:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?                                                                                                                
If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

I have tried running:

```
systemctl start docker
```

But then I get the error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.                    
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong , please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From WSL you actually want to use Docker from the Windows host:

1. Install Docker Desktop for Windows
2. Go to the settings > Resources > WSL Integration and flip the switch for the Distros where you want Docker enabled.
   [image: Screenshot]
3. You should now be able to run `docker -v` in your WSL commandline and get an output of the Docker version

Comment: If I run docker -v at the moment it does give me the docker version, but I am still unable to build.

Comment: Does `docker-compose -v` also work? The error you posted above should not occur when the `-v` commands work

Comment: When running docker -v I get the docker version and a build number. When running docker-compose -v I get the docker version and it sais build unknown

Comment: Sorry, I have never encountered that problem before. I'll leave my answer up for future people, since every time I had that first error, this was the solution. You may want to add the outputs of `docker -v` and `docker-compose -v` to your question, maybe this will help someone who knows what's going on here.

Comment: So even though I could see the docker version, I still followed these steps and it does work now. Thank you :)